# How to set "key" for opacity widget

Tags: flutter, key, opacity

I want use a `Opacity` widget **child** in a `Opacity` widget **parent** like this :

```
class EmptyAlbumArtContainer extends StatelessWidget {

...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color:Colors.red,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 1 - animation.value,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: 0.5,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue
          )
        )
      ),
   );
  }
}
...
```

But the opacity value the father becomes zero , suddenly!!!!
is this the problem with the key vlaue?

**Update**

I create a class like [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) library.

[image]

**red** : is parent.

**orange** : is only a default album art with below code.
As move up, the opacity of the red box decreases.

```
class DefaultAlbumArt extends StatelessWidget{

  DefaultAlbumArt({Key key}) : super(key:key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient:  LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                stops: [
                  0.0,
                  0.85
                ],
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFF47ACE1),
                  Color(0xFFDF5F9D)
                ]
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: 0.5,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.music_note,
                color: Colors.black87,
                size: screenAwareSize(context, 40),
              ),
            )
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is your objective of having 2 different Opacity widgets, one being the parent of the other? This will help us help you.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: I appreciate the update. But I still don't understand why you want to chain 2 opacity widgets. Please tell us what you want to achieve. Not how you want to do it, what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: sorry!, No special reason! , opacity child only create a albumArt with opacity: 0.5

Comment: You are already using a gradient to achieve the effect. Why do you need 2 opacities? It's very difficult to understand if you don't tell us what is in your mind.